# Visual Studio Activity Log - Time is start or end of task?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to troubleshoot a huge delay in my Visual Studio 2012 when it loads. I can't seem to find a good description for the Time column. Is that the time when the event **starts** or **completes**? That makes a huge difference in determining which event is causing the issue.

```
  <entry>
    <record>24</record>
    <time>2012/12/07 23:41:25.360</time> <!-- This line -->
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{DA9FB551-C724-11D0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}</guid>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event logging is done synchronously--a log entry occurs at an instant in time, it isn't associated with a long running process that starts and completes.  The time is whatever time the entry was logged to the activity log.

The log entry you quote was logged upon entry of the `CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage` function.  Any component can write an entry to the activity log at any time, though, so it's not possible to say *in general* when a log entry occurs relative to the operation to which it refers.  The text of each log entry should provide some indication, though.